# Why is switching a Vue component reloading the page?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have something that looks like this (in a Nuxt application):

```
<template>
  <component :is="dynamicComponent"></component>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  components: {
    Component1,
    Component2
  },
  created() {
    this.$nuxt.$on("switch1", () => {
      this.dynamicComponent = Component1;
    });
    this.$nuxt.$on("switch2", () => {
      this.dynamicComponent = Component2;
    });
  },
  data() {
    return {
      dynamicComponent: Component1
    };
  }
}
</script>
```

So an event triggers switching the component. However, if I try to switch from the default *Component1* to *Component2*, *Component2* briefly appears, only for the page to be reloaded with Component1. That seems to be such a basic thing and I have no idea why it's not working.

EDIT:
I found the mistake. Somehow during refactoring/reformatting the call got changed from:

```
        <a class="nav-item" href="#" @click="$nuxt.$emit('switch2')">..</a>
```

to

```
        <a class="nav-item" href="" @click="$nuxt.$emit('switch2')">..</a>
```

which triggers a reload of the page on click.

Comment: What triggers `switch1` and `switch2` events? Can you provide a reproduction in Codesandbox? This should be reproducible in a Vue sandbox, where `this.$nuxt` is replaced with `this.$root`.

Comment: You lack information in your example, hard to help, you should provide a codesandbox or something like it.
I'll leave you here an example I made based on your problem so you can change it according to your error.
The one I provide seems to be working fine, so let us know what the issue is by chaning this codepen to your problem:

https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-cache-vtlfw?file=/pages/index.vue

Comment: Thank for the input to both. I found my mistake, it's in the trigger. I'll edit the post above.